# How does Spring Security works?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

I'm a newbie on springboot 3.1 + webflux + kotlin.

I'm studying about spring security after watching the official documentation and various blogs, but the principle is not coming out and there are so many articles on how to use it, so I'm asking you a question.

I wonder how the spring executes "strangeNaming" function.

**I'm not inheriting something and overriding it, but I wonder how it works even if I write the function name as I want.**

Please save me.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun strangeNaming(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain {
        return http.authorizeExchange {
            it.anyExchange().permitAll()
        }.exceptionHandling {
//            Configures what to do when the application request authentication
            it.authenticationEntryPoint { exchange, ex ->
                Mono.fromRunnable {
                    exchange.response.statusCode = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED
                }
            }
//            Configures what to do when an authenticated user does not hold a required authority
            it.accessDeniedHandler { exchange, denied ->
                Mono.fromRunnable {
                    exchange.response.statusCode = HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN
                }
            }

        }.build()
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you ask why `strangeNaming` get even executed since it doesn't call anywhere directly? I mean not about it's implementation

Comment: yes. I couldn't figure out how the spring framework works inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring treats each class marked with `@Configuration` as a configuration file. In particular, Spring handles all `@Bean`-annotated methods. If a method is annotated as `@Bean`, it would be executed during context creation whatever method is named. Method shouldn't be called by you directly neither it's name be specified anywhere. `@Bean` is enough.

An object return by that method would be a Spring bean and would be present in a Spring application context. Then it is up to Spring Security to apply and use that bean.

[Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html) is official docs to `@Bean`. [Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/configuration/webflux.html) is Spring WebFlux Security guide briefly covering `SecurityWebFilterChain`.

Answer (score 0):

A good article about SecurityWebFilterChain, you will find a reference why adapters was deprecated in spring-security and after removed: [Spring Security without the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter)

Comment: Thanks to answer. i will read that :)

Comment: I read that, but the thing i wonder is not why adapter was depreacted.

i wonder how the spring framework identifies and executes functions.

Comment: Spring Security selects one SecurityWebFilterChain @Bean for each request. And has a request matcher that is used to decide whether to apply it to an HTTP request

Comment: Can I know the overall flow regarding the call stack?
It's not even in the official document, so it's hard to figure out how to customize it to fit the service.

For example, who is running SecurityWebFilterChain bean

Comment: I know that the arhitecture overview not are modified and it is the same for reactive and servlet applications. You can to get it on Architecture section on documentation(servlet/architecture)